# How to opacity TableView when user tapped on SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am a new IOS programmer. I want to build an app which quite similar to default IOS app which called "Phone", for that app i focus on Contact only which i have implement `searchBar` already. For my problem is that i want to make view becomes opacity when user tapped on `searchBar`.

What i have tried so far
[Here is detail of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb6ZW.jpg)

here what i expected [Here is detail of my expectation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnP4r.jpg)

For addition part is when user click on that dark view, the keyboard should be dismissed as well.

How to keep `searchBar` stays stick to navigationBar when user scroll up?

Thank for your help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618660-dimsbackgroundduringpresentation)

```
let searchController = UISearchController()
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: Oh my god, that is help me a lot, thank you so much @RajeshKumar

Comment: So do you know how to keep `searchBar` stick when user scroll up?